# Parent class referencing subclass static members throws ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**Updated problem:**

Can I design a parent class to access subclass static members without throwing the error?  If this is possible, how does one go about it?

---

Basically, I have a DbHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.  I've also implemented the necessary methods required.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb.sqlite3";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static final String CREATE_TABLE_FOO = "CREATE TABLE " + FooAdapter.TABLE_NAME
      + " (" + FooAdapter.COLUMN_BAR + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)";

  public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FOO);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Then I extended this class into a more specific subclass FooAdapter

```
public class FooAdapter extends DbHelper {
  public static String TABLE_NAME = "foo";
  public static String COLUMN_BAR = "bar";

  public FooAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  // table specific methods, select, insert, delete
}
```

After help from the comments, I've figured out that the error is because DbHelper is accessing FooAdapter's static members but FooAdapter is a subclass of DbHelper.

So, If I instantiate FooAdapter in an activity, I get the ExceptionInInitializerError.

```
FooAdapter fooDb = new FooAdapter(this); // throws ExceptionInInitializerError
```

But if I instantiate DbHelper first, everything runs fine.

```
DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this); 
FooAdapter fooDb = new FooAdapter(this); // no error
```

I checked logcat and the last line of error says `DbHelper.<clinit>(DbHelper.java...)`

Comment: `clinit` refers to class initialization, e.g. static variables or static initializer blocks. The code you posted doesn't show problems in that area though.

Comment: maybe because I referenced a static member from the extending class in the extended class and it becomes circular?  I'll try to get rid of these static first.

Comment: The stacktrace shows the specific line where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I managed to find out the source of the problem, and it isn't related to android or sqlite at all.  I guess I'll have to redefine my classes in such a way that static members from the subclass is not referenced by the parent class.  I edited the question to reflect real problem.